# Should we have a tag for car titles?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created a tag called "Title" but we've chosen not to use it previously. We have lots of specific titling questions. Should we have this tag?

Comment: Do you think that the "[car](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car)" tag is not sufficient?

Comment: @BenMiller If a house tag would be sufficient for all questions related to mortgages, homeowners insurance, title-insurance, etc.

Answer (score 3):

adding the single tag [title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title) is problematic.

In the United States the word title also applies to real estate questions. We have many questions about adding people to a house title and the purchasing of title insurance.

Now we do have a tag for  [title-insurance](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title-insurance) but we do have real estate questions that mention title but aren't concerned about title insurance.

[Add spouse to a joint tenant title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/70693/add-spouse-to-a-joint-tenant-title?s=4|2.5108) [mortgage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage) [real-estate](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real-estate)

[Fiancée not on the mortgage but wants to be on the title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/61516/fianc%c3%a9e-not-on-the-mortgage-but-wants-to-be-on-the-title?s=11|1.7230) [mortgage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage) [loans](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/loans)

[Would it be wise to add a person to the Title of my property to obtain a loan?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24273/would-it-be-wise-to-add-a-person-to-the-title-of-my-property-to-obtain-a-loan?s=21|1.4959) [mortgage](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mortgage) [personal-loan](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personal-loan)

I would propose two tags: [car-title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car-title) and [house-title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-title)

Comment: We are using the term "auto-loan". Should we use "car-title" or "automobile-title" ? auto is kind of non intuitive in this context, it is more intuitive for loans.

Comment: would a single "asset-title" be more relevant and generic?

Comment: At least in the US, car titles are a _very_ common thing (because they're used for "title loans" mostly); other assets either don't have actual titles or you just don't think about them, beyond real estate anyway.

Comment: I would use [tag:vehicle-title] or [tag:auto-title] and synonym the other to it as well as [tag:car-title] so people get it right when they search.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to propose this separately for voting purposes, though you can assume most of what mhoran_psprep's post says here: I think [title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/title) is ambiguous, so we need one specific for [things that you drive].

I think [vehicle-title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vehicle-title) is the best tag title, because it's the most common phrasing (see for example [this page](http://www.dmv.org/il-illinois/title-transfers.php), and [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_title)).  Googling "car title" brings up Vehicle Title pages, for example.

I agree that we do need a tag for it, because (at least in the US) vehicle title is something that often comes up on its own merits in financial activities, between title loans and vehicle sales, both of which are commonly done by individuals without any representation.  House titles perhaps should also get a tag, though usually those come in context of other things AND have a representative of some sort (lawyer or real estate agent) in the mix; if we did have a tag for that, I would suggest something appropriate as well that was more generic than [house-title](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-title), but I won't include those suggestions here to avoid muddling the voting.

Answer (score 0):

We could use car-title and house-title, but those terms are not precise and are not commonly used anywhere. Titling is for property, and cars fit in that category. Many categories of real estate have nothing to do with houses. I don't think it would be terribly confusing to have some real-estate questions as well as automobile/boat questions all sharing a title tag.